# Catch read error on EF 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a DB with no constraints (given, not changeable). My model look like

```
public MyModel 
{ 
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // Even if database column 'Value' could be NULL,
    // the model - from business view - could not.
    public long Value { get; set; }
}
```

My data I'd like to read is

```
Id Value
1  1
2  2
3  NULL
4  4
```

When I read with with DBContext.MyModel.ToList() it fails, of course. Is there any possibility to catch the error on 3rd row and return the 3 valid ones?

I don't dependent on EF but I like an automatic mapping between DB an Code.

**Update:** 
It seems I wasn't specific enough. I need the 3 rows AS WELL AS a notification for the error.

Additional I've created a simple case for demo. In real life I have around 800 tables with up to 250 columns. I can't catch anything by model modification like dates out of range, missing relationships and other stuff.

What I really need is a try..catch for every row or an event on row reading failure, something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved. Not very elegant, but functional.

```
var query = _DBContext
    .Database
    .SqlQuery<MyModel>("SELECT * FROM MyModel");

var result = new List<MyModel>();
var enumerator = query.GetEnumerator();
while (true)
    {
    try
        {
        var success = enumerator.MoveNext();
        if (!success)
            break;

        var model = enumerator.Current;
        result.Add(model);
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

return result;
```

Comment: This would perhaps work even with normal linq `IQueryable` query. Did you try it? It would be nicer than `.SqlQuery<MyModel>("SELECT * FROM MyModel")`?

Comment: Yes, i tried. With an `IQueryable`, I get always the same (first) record in the loop. No idea why. If there is an more elegant way, I'll use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `nullable type`

```
public MyModel 
{ 
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // Even if database column 'Value' could be NULL,
    // the model - from business view - could not.
    public long? Value { get; set; }
}
```

And also, in your select query, you should exlude `Value = null`

```
var myModel = models.Where(x => x.Value != null);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this hide the error, but doesn't catch them.

Comment: Hi @Florian, it did not hide the error. The implementation should be like that since Value is nullable. You have to filter out the value after selecting.

Comment: yes, you're right. My example is too simple. In fact, I have about 800 tables up to 250 columns. Error check for every case isn't practical for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
var list = from m in DBContext.MyModel
           where (m != null)
           select m;
```

And then just convert var list to a List of your choosing.

**Edit 1**

```
var myModel = models.Where(x => x.Value != null).ToList();
```

As kienct89 suggested might also work.

**Edit 2**

There are multiple options for "catching" the error

If you want to throw an exception just use this:

```
if(myList.Count() < DBContext.MyModel.Count()){
    Exception myException = new Exception("Not all items ware correctly loaded");
    throw myException;
    }
```

OR create a seperate array with the faulty ones:

```
var faultyList = from m in DBContext.MyModel
               where (m == null)
               select m;
```

Or:

```
var faultyList= models.Where(x => x.Value == null).ToList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this hide the error, but doesn't catch them.

Comment: What do you mean by "catch", do you want them in a seperate array, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I meen something like a array with errors, or try catch blog for the single line could not read, ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but if you want to get a reflection of what's in the table, then why not make your model match the query? If `Value` can be `NULL`, then make `Value` nullable (i.e. define it as `long?`).

That way, you can simply do:

```
var records = DbContext.MyModel.ToList();
```

If you then want to filter out the `NULL`s, you can do:

```
records.Where(r => r.Value.HasValue)
```

And if you want the ones with `NULL`s you can do:

```
records.Where(r => !r.Value.HasValue)
```

Or if you want to know whether *any* row had a `NULL` you could do:

```
records.Any(r => !r.Value.HasValue)
```

Comment: Sorry, my example is too simple. What I really need is a try..catch for every row or an event on row reading failure, something like this. See my update in original post.